# "Recycling" names within a spring application context

Tags: java, spring

lets say, I have a lot of stuff within my spring application context which looks like that

```
<bean name="foo.0001" class="com.example.MyClass">
    <property name="name" value="foo.name.0001"/>
    <property name="zap">
        <bean class="com.example.Other">
            <property name="name" value="foo.name.0001"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="bar">
        <bean class="com.example.NextOther">
            <property name="name" value="foo.name.0001"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

so the string foo.name.0001 appears within the bean definition several times. Because it is a larger system with several blocks of this configuration, it is quite annoying to modify **each** of those ids. Ideally I would want to set it only **once within a block**. Is there a possibility to set some kind of property which exists only in a local scope of a bean definition?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If the name values in the child beans are meant to be the same as the name in the parent bean would you not be better referencing the parent bean somehow?

Comment: I just want to remove the redundandcy of having to specify those names again. Because if I copy the whole block I have to change each of those occurences in this case 3 times, but I want to adjust it only once. The problem is, that in the past during configuring the application, I had copy & paste errors because in some cases I forgot to change the name in a definition, which could lead to quite subtle errors.

Comment: Ok but is there an underlying reason why these names are the same? If so, could you not use references somehow instead of having to specify them many times?

Comment: That is my question, the only need I have that the scope of the reference is only within the defined bean, because if the name of the reference is different there is no difference to specifying the name in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how that would logically work, as you would still have to reference that value somehow to pass it to the nested beans.  If you are worried about defining it multiple times, you can have a look at Springs [PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.html).  It will allow you to the following:

```
<property name="bar">
   <bean class="com.example.NextOther">
      <property name="name" value="${foo.name.001}"/>
   </bean>
</property>
```

This would allow you to define it once, and reference it from multiple locations.

Comment: But if I copy that block I would still have to change **all** occurences of foo.name.001, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much effort you want to put into to this but your requirements could be fufilled by a spring custom namespace. These are ideal when you have lots of identical blocks of beans each configured differently.

Basically you'd define the xml schema then write a bean definition parser that sets up the beans as required.

See here for more details:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2008/jw-02-springcomponents.html

This is how Spring security simplified its xml configuration.

Comment: Fair enough - but you dont have many other options in spring. 

You could make a factory class that creates the hierarchy for you.

All in all I don't think you'll find a solution to this that doesn't require some effort.